# Redirect not working properly

Tags: php, jquery

Its a very silly problem but somehow it is not working
I have a function to create a file, if it goes through with it i want it to redirect the user to X page.. in this case 1.php.... but somehow is not working :S why?

```
    //Creates File, populates it and redirects the user.
if (createfile($dbFile)) { 
    header('Location: 1.php');
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`exit()`](http://php.net/exit) after sending a redirect header:

```
 if (createfile($dbFile)) {
     header('Location: http://yoursite.com/path/to/1.php', true, 302);
     exit();
 }
```

Otherwise, PHP continues to execute. If you `exit()`, the client receives the header right after you make the call to `header()`.

You should also heed this warning on the [PHP docs page for `header()`](http://php.net/header):

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to [Location:](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `dirname()` to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an absolute location?

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: yipee someone correctly using an absolute URI as required in the specs

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
if (createfile($dbFile)) { 
   header("Refresh: 0; URL=1.php");
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar sounding problem where code was still being executed after the header location. That's why I always do exit(); afterwards